# Error in checking that Edit text in android is empty

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm implementing a simple adder application. When I click the sum without entering any numbers the application crashes. Why? I defined the function such that when either `num1` or `num2` is empty it should print `"Invalid---"`. Why is it crashing then?

When i click the sum without entering any number it crashes .Why?
As i already defined function when either entry among num1 or num2 is empty
it should print "Invalid---" .

[image: Screenshot of the app]

My java code for `MainActivity` is here:

```
import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onButtonClick(View v){
    EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNum1);
    EditText b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNum2);
    TextView c =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

    String x=a.getText().toString();
    String y=b.getText().toString();

    if( (x!="" && y!="")) {
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(x);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(y);
        int num3 = num1 + num2;
        c.setText("Good entry");
    }
    else{
        c.setText("Invalid num1 or num2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat.

Comment: As i just started android .So i don't know how to get logcat.

Comment: No worries, which IDE are you using to code? android studio? if nothing else works, simply use 'adb logcat'. Google will give you more detailed steps. Debugging is essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try using this --

```
if((!"".equals(x)) && (!"".equals(y))) {
  int num1 = Integer.parseInt(x);
  int num2 = Integer.parseInt(y);
  int num3 = num1 + num2;
  c.setText("Good entry");
}
```

Comment: Oh ! It worked i got my mistake i cannot simply compare x to "" by x!=""
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please up-vote or accept my answer if it solved your problem or if it was helpful to you? Thanks :)